# comparação de datas com javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho dois campos do tipo `date` no meu formulário, o campo `data_inicio` e `data_fim`.

Estou precisando montar um `script` que quando eu terminar de preencher as datas, ou seja quando os campos perderem o foco, for emitido um alerta avisando se `data_inicio` é maior do que a `data_fim`, sendo que a `data_inicio` **jamais** pode ser maior do que a `data_fim`.

Já fiz um script usando o evento `onclik`, mas ele só avisa quando clico no `submit`.

**Segue o código abaixo:**

```js
 function comparadatas()
 {
   var data_inicio = document.getElementById("data_inicio").value;
   var data_fim = document.getElementById("data_fim").value;
    
    if(data_inicio > data_fim){
        alert("ERRO! A DATA DE NOTICAÇÃO NAO PODE SER MAIOR DO QUE A DATA DE COMPARECIMENTO");   
    }
 }
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="data_inicio">Data Inicio</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_inicio" id="data_inicio"><br/>

  <label for="data_fim">Data Final</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_fim" id="data_fim"><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="REALIZAR CADASTRO" onclick="comparadatas()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar o evento [**onblur**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onblur). Esse evento será enviando quando um determinado elemento perder o foco.

Você pode passar o atributo `onblur="comparadatas"` nos elementos de data ou utilizar `Js` para definir. Eu utilizei `js` no exemplo abaixo por questão de gosto.

```js
const data_inicio = document.getElementById("data_inicio");
const data_fim = document.getElementById("data_fim");

data_inicio.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  comparadatas();
});

data_fim.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  comparadatas();
});

function comparadatas() {
  if (data_inicio.value == "" || data_fim.value == "") return false;
  
  if (data_inicio.value > data_fim.value) {
    alert("ERRO! A DATA DE NOTICAÇÃO NAO PODE SER MAIOR DO QUE A DATA DE COMPARECIMENTO");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="data_inicio">Data Inicio</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_inicio" id="data_inicio"><br/>

  <label for="data_fim">Data Final</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_fim" id="data_fim"><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="REALIZAR CADASTRO" onclick="comparadatas()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function comparadatas() {
  const data_inicio = document.getElementById("data_inicio");
  const data_fim = document.getElementById("data_fim");
  if (data_inicio.value == "" || data_fim.value == "") return false;

  if (data_inicio.value > data_fim.value) {
    alert("A DATA DE NOTICAÇÃO NAO PODE SER MAIOR DO QUE A DATA DE COMPARECIMENTO!");
  }
}
</script>

<form>
  <label for="data_inicio">Data Inicio</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_inicio" id="data_inicio"><br/>

  <label for="data_fim">Data Final</label>
  <input type="date" name="data_fim" id="data_fim" onblur="comparadatas()"><br/>

</form>
```

Comment: Bom dia pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui resolver

Comment: Faltou marcar a outra como correta. '-'